# Redirecting user on failed Accounts.validateLoginAttempt

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

all.  I'm working on a new Meteor project, and I'm using e-mail verification (mandatory) for all new accounts.  I want to keep people from being able to log into the application when their e-mail isn't verified, but I have a question.

I'm using the following code:

```
// Refuse login from non-verified users
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(function(attempt){
    if (attempt.user && attempt.user.emails && !attempt.user.emails[0].verified ) {

        return false; // the login is aborted
    }
    return true;
});
```

To handle the 'rejected login', but I want to redirect the user to a page on the app that tells them why they can't log in (a simple view that will say 'hey, go verify your e-mail'.

Seeing as how this bit of code is server-side, how am I supposed to redirect the **client** to a page based on the failure of their login attempt?  I'm confused.

I'm using Iron Router, and the newest version of Meteor available.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: are you using `Meteor.loginWithPassword` for login ?

Comment: I'm not really using any manual login procedures, but I am only using `accounts-password`, not any OAuth-based providers or anything like that.

Comment: are you using `accounts-ui` package or any other package for login form

Comment: I'm using `useraccounts:bootstrap` to handle the login form.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no official way  of doing this. If you're using `loginWithPasword` you can use callback method to redirect the user to another page.

Comment: Hmm.   I could try that.  I've never tried to do stuff with loginWithPassword before, I guess it couldn't hurt.  Are there tutorials on it anywhere I could find?

Comment: IDK, this is easy, create a form take username and pwd from user and onsubmit event call `Meteor.loginWithPassword(email,pws,callback)`

Comment: docs link http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithpassword, If login success you will get no params in callback , if fails you'll get one error param